Why there is no std::numbers::sqrtpi_v?
I have a std::normal_distribution<RealType> normal_distribution and want to use its normalization constant in a constexpr. Unfortunately, I cannot use normal_distribution.stddev() * std::sqrt(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<RealType>), since std::sqrt is not constexpr. But there is also no std::numbers::sqrtpi_v<RealType>, only std::numbers::inv_sqrtpi_v<RealType>. So I need to use normal_distribution.stddev() * std::numbers::sqrt2_v<RealType> / std::numbers::inv_sqrtpi_v<RealType>. Why is that? Am I loosing something here? Can this constexpr solution be less accurate than normal_distribution.stddev() * std::sqrt(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<RealType>)?

Just test it and see with numbers.

They only set out to provide definitions for the most commonly used mathematical constants and I'm guessing sqrtpi isn't among them.

Well there is in boost : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/boost/math/constants/constants.hpp, root_two_pi (you can copy it from there if you want and make a constexpr constant for your own code). E.g something like : template<typename T> static constexpr T root_two_pi() { return 2.50662827463100050241576528481104525300698674060993831662992357634229365460784197494659583837805726611600997267e+00; }. In the end I think C++ just went for the bare minimum (because once you start you end up with a lot of constants... like the boost header)

template <class T> inline constexpr T sqrtpi_v = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T>(1.772453850905516027298167483341145182L); and inline constexpr double sqrtpi = sqrtpi_v<double>; should work.


But there is also no std::numbers::sqrtpi_v<RealType>, only std::numbers::inv_sqrtpi_v<RealType>. [...] Why is that?

It may seem arbitrary ... and it kinda is.
inv_sqrt_pi is necessary to obtain the POSIX constant M_2_SQRTPI (2 / sqrt(pi)) with maximum precision.
The ability to do so is one design goal of P0631R8: Math Constants (see 4.0 Design goals).
This is possible because multiplication with 2 merely increases the exponent of a floating-point number by 1, but doesn't drop any precision in the mantissa.
On the other hand, sqrt(pi) in itself is unnecessary/unfit for computing any POSIX constants.

Can [normal_distribution.stddev() * std::numbers::sqrt2_v<RealType> / std::numbers::inv_sqrtpi_v<RealType>] solution be less accurate than normal_distribution.stddev() * std::sqrt(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<RealType>)?

The precision loss should be more or less the same in either case.
In the workaround, you are performing a multiplication and division, both of which require rounding.
In the std::sqrt version, you are taking a square root and multiplying, and both operations may lose precision.
C++20 workaround
As pointed out by commenters, you can also make your own constant:
template <std::floating_point T>
inline constexpr auto sqrtpi_v = static_cast<T>(1.772453850905516027298167483341145182L);

inline constexpr double sqrtpi = sqrtpi_v<double>;

C++26/GCC workaround

Unfortunately, I cannot use normal_distribution.stddev() * std::sqrt(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<RealType>), since std::sqrt is not constexpr.

Note that std::sqrt is constexpr since C++26.
If you use GCC's __builtin_sqrt, you might be able to get a constexpr square root even in C++20.
In other words, you can use std::sqrt(std::numbers::pi), although this isn't guaranteed to be the most accurate value.
